# 'apiKey.id is required' error thrown when using express-stormpath with node.js

Tags: stormpath, express-stormpath

I am using express-stormpath with node.js to set up a backend server. This is a snippet of my server.js code where I get an error thrown -

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
 apiKeyFile: './config/.stormpath/apikey.properties',
 application: '<API_HREF>',
 secretKey: security.stormpath_secret_key
 }));
```

This is the error -

```
$ node server.js
../webservices/node_modules/express-    
stormpath/node_modules/stormpath/lib/authc/RequestAuthenticator.js:8
throw new Error('apiKey.id is required.');
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're using the latest version of the [express-stormpath](https://github.com/stormpath/express-stormpath) library, which is why you're probably having issues. As of the `2.0.0` release, the library uses new configuration options.

Here's an example of the same thing using the new options:

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
 client: {
    apiKey: {
      file: './config/.stormpath/apikey.properties'
    }
 },
 application: {
   href: '<API_HREF>',
 }
}));
```

**NOTE**: No `secretKey` is required, as this is generated automatically from your Stormpath API key secret =)

We've made many new changes in the latest library releases that enable all sorts of new, cool stuff! <3

Comment: Now I am getting this error: 
/node_modules/express-stormpath/node_modules/stormpath/lib/Config.js:57
      throw new Error('Unable to read properties file: ' + apiKeyFileName);

I am using 2.0.12 version of express-stormpath

Comment: This means your apiKey file path is invalid -- are you sure your file exists and is named `./config/.stormpath/apikey.properties`? Check the spelling / capitalization.

Comment: I checked the spelling and capitalization. The file exists. 
Where can I find docs for the new API version, since there seem to be a lot of changes to stormpath?

Comment: All of our docs are on our website here: http://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/latest/

Comment: So you gave the wrong answer. It should have been 
apiKey: {
       id:'<id>',
       secret:'<secret'>
}

Comment: It works with either apiKey: `{ id: '...', secret: '...' }` OR `apiKey: { file: 'path_to_file' }`. I'm the author of the library =)

Comment: Nice! The library is really awesome. The latter option didn't work for me though.

Comment: Hmm, I'll add in some regression tests and make sure that gets resolved if it isn't working for some reason. We do pretty extensive testing on releases, but it's totally possible something fell through the cracks!